# start and stop "tail -f" in local server and remote ssh server using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, tail

I am basically trying to write a script to capture live log from local(server1) and remote server(server2) in real time.
the log files are stored in the same directory on both servers.

for exmaple:    /var/log/test/test.log

now i want to write a script in server1 and capture the increasing logs in both nodes.

basic logic of the shell(not real bash code):

```
tail -f /var/log/test/test.log > /some/local/dir/sever1.log &
ssh server2 and tail -f /var/log/test/test.log > /some/local/dir/server2.log &
if [ exit or ctrl+c ] 
kill "tail -f pid" in server1
kill "tail -f pid" in server2.
exit
```

I am a bash noob and hope some one can help me realize the goal.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

As long as you haven't [`nohup`'d or `disown`'d](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3886/165677) your scripts, terminating the parent script should terminate its children processes as well.

Alternately, you can capture the value of `$!` which contains the PID of the most recently run background process.  You can use these values with `kill` to have the parent script end them.  To make sure that your parent script terminates them on exit, you'll need to set up an exit [`trap`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html).

Comment: how can i kill the PID in remote server at the same time of local tail -f command?
and exit signal should be caught in both tail commands.

Comment: You shouldn't need to.  In your example code, it's `ssh` that gets run in the background on the local server, not `tail` on the remote server.  By killing the local `ssh` it will terminate the remote commands it had running by sending a SIGHUP.